# Correct use of the Rack::Response-Object in Server-Answer

Tags: ruby, rack

i have a question on how to make proper of use the **Rack::Response**-Object in a server-response.

In `line 711` the method `Rack::Lint#each` (https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/lint.rb#L711) asserts among others that `part.kind_of? String` such that `assert("Body yielded non-string value #{part.inspect}")`

The most basic response is a triplet like

> [status, headers, body]

I got an error message, when I put the `Rack::Response`-Object in the triplet like that:

> [status, headers, rs]

where rs is the Response-Object.

I got it to work with

> [status, headers, st.body]

however, as it then passes the above-mentioned assertion !

My question is only if this makes correct use of `Rack::Response`, or if not, what are then the proper ways of using it in a Server-Response.

Thank you very much

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

`Rack::Response` is simply an interface that is new'd up with 3 arguments, the body, the status code and the headers.

The body argument can either respond to `#to_str` or it must implement `#each` and whatever is yielded to `#each` must respond to `#to_s`.

So as a straightforward answer consider this to be valid:

```
response = Rack::Response.new(
  ['a','series', 'of', 'strings'],
  200,
  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
)
```

This is valid as well

```
response = Rack::Response.new(
  '{}',
  200,
  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
)
```

Or if you have a custom class that say is proxying a response from an API, this would also suffice:

```
class ApiClient
  def initialize
    @response = get_something
  end

  def each
    @response.chars.each { |el| yield el }
  end

  private

  def get_something
    "a string of responses"
  end
end

response = Rack::Response.new(
  ApiClient.new,
  200,
  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
)
```

When you're ready to return your response object back to the caller, you simply called `#finish` on your `Rack::Response` instance.  This is also aliased as `#to_a` and `#to_ary`.

Comment: Thank you very much. And could you answer me what are the valid ways of using the Response-Object in the server-answer, that is, as return value of the rack-endpoint ?

Like, having the whole response-object be the last statement instead of the triple [status, headers, body] ? Or a combination of both?